What is the most efficient, optimal, solution for the multi-way number partitioning problem?
I looked around the internet (and this site) for a solution to the multi-way number partitioning problem, which is an efficiency problem in which you need to partition S, a list of numbers, into k subsets, so that the difference between the largest subset and the smallest subset is as low as possible (for example, if S = [1, 2, 3] and k = 2, then the algorithm should return [1, 2], [3]). I am trying to find an algorithm that always returns the most optimal partition (not an approximate result), while being as efficient as possible.
I've tried using a brute-force algorithm, however that was getting extremely slow at higher k and n (the length of S) values, as its worst-case efficiency is k^n, so I was wondering if/what any faster, while still exact, algorithms are. I'm implementing in JavaScript, so that may have resulted in the slow speeds.
I'm also new to this site, so any feedback would be great. Thank you!

Are you OK with exponential-time algorithms?  Are the numbers in the list fairly small, or are they very large?  If they are small, there is a pseudopolynomial time algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning#Exact_algorithms; there are other algorithms there if the numbers are not small.  How large are typical values $n,k$?

@D.W. n would be as large as 24, and k as large as 5 :)

The problem is NP-hard, so you shouldn't expect any general algorithm that is always optimal, always works, and is efficient.
I suspect a pragmatic approach is to use an integer linear programming (ILP) solver.  Let $s_1,\dots,s_n$ be the $n$ numbers, i.e., $S=[s_1,\dots,s_n]$.  Define zero-or-one variables $x_{ij}$, with the intended meaning that $x_{ij}=1$ if $s_i$ is assigned to the $j$th partition.  Then write down some linear inequalities that characterize what counts as a valid $k$-way partitioning.  Specifically:

For each $i$, $\sum_j x_{ij}=1$ (each item assigned to exactly one partition).

For each $j$, $\ell \le \sum_i x_{ij} \le u$, where $\ell,u$ are variables representing the size of the smallest and largest partition.


Then, ask the ILP solver to find a solution that minimizes the objective function $u - \ell$.  The optimal solution to the ILP should be the optimal solution to your multiway partitioning problem.
No guarantees that this will work well in practice, as the problem is exponential, but it might work in an acceptable amount of time for your problem sizes.  It shouldn't be too hard to try.
Also, if you're willing to accept approximate but not optimal solutions, some ILP solvers have an option to terminate the search after a fixed timeout, and output the best solution they have found so far.
